# How Can I stop website elements from being pushed up when my form automatically resizes?

Tags: html, css, forms, positioning

I am making a test landing page and using a Gravity Form for the signup, my problem is that when the form automatically resizes after completion (just leaving room for the confirmation message) it pushes up elements below it and breaks the layout. I'm sure its a simple solution but I cant seem to find it. Code structure:

```
<h3 style="line-height: 15px;">SOME TEXT</h3>
<h3>MORE TEXT</h3>
<h3 style="line-height: 15px;">MORE TEXT</h3>
<h4>MORE TEXT</h4>
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-492" style="position: absolute; top: 430px; left: 80px;" src="image.png"width="350" height="202" /></a>
<div style="width: 40%; 
            background-color: #ffce32; 
            border: 3px solid #8E0F0F; 
            position: relative; bottom: 180px; left: 610px; 
            padding: 10px; border-radius:20px;">[my gravity form]</div>

<div style="position: relative; bottom: 160px;">
    <h4 style="text-align: center;">TEXT</h4>
    <img>
    <h4 style="text-align: center;">TEXT</h4>
    <div class="my_gallery" style="margin-left: 110px;"></div>
    <h4 style="text-align: center;">TEXT</h4>
    <p>TEXT</p>
    <h4 style="text-align: center;">TEXT</h4>
</div>
```

The issue is with the div right below the form getting pushed up and breaking the layout when the form shrinks.

Comment: Perhaps you can show us a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your css + html? Is there another stylesheet in place?

Comment: You have a couple of html errors: an `a` tag closing the `img` tag on  line 5, and a perhaps(?) pointless `img` tag in the second `div`

Comment: @ultranaut it actually looks like the image tag is self closing but yes there is a random closing anchor tag in there and a random img. I don't think that'd cause any problems though

Comment: @JeffLauder I was just pointing them out to him, I've got no idea whether they're causing his problems.

Comment: Yeah the Image Tags are there like that just to explain the placing, They are properly done in the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want things to move around when things disappear you could try adding a non breaking space to the div so that it is still rendered. Also add a minimum height to the div so it can't get too small, Something like:

```
<div style="width: 40%; 
        background-color: #ffce32; 
        border: 3px solid #8E0F0F; 
        position: relative; bottom: 180px; left: 610px;
        min-height:400px; /*you'll have to experiment here to figure out what works*/
        padding: 10px; border-radius:20px;">[my gravity form] &nbsp;</div>
```

I would also suggest using classes and a css file instead of adding a style to each div.

Comment: I did try that but it doesn't work very well. I'm looking for something that would basically prevent the div below the form from moving upwards regardless of the form's size. But I still need it to be able to move down (which it does fine right now) when the form expends because page 2 is bigger than page one. So Form goes from height A on page one to bigger height B on page 2 and then much smaller height C on page 3. And I need the content below it to adapt but without crashing into the top elements when the form height is smaller than the starting one.

Comment: You can set a min-height on the top content of the standard sized form (depending on what the form has in it once it's closed you'll probably still need the &nbsp;)... I'll adjust my answer

Comment: Thanks! The min-height was the eureka moment, I set it for the top level div and it works perfectly now!